# Return a Promise for a JSON POST

Tags: node.js, comparative-review, json, promise, async-await

Given this method, we don't know which syntax is the more appropriate.

```
async finishUpgrade({id}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: this.apiUrl + `${id}/?action=proceed`,
        body: {}
        json: true
      };

      try {
        const res = await req(options);
        resolve(res);
      } catch(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

As you can see we use `return new Promise(...)`.

Would it be correct/a better way to refactor it this way:

```
async finishUpgrade({id}) {
  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: this.apiUrl + `${id}/?action=proceed`,
    body: {}
    json: true
  };

  try {
    const res = await req(options);
    return Promise.resolve(res);
  } catch(err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2.

Comment: You are right we'll ask another question. Our bad!

Comment: @200_success - I'm OK with the edit.  I've updated my answer to include that case too.

Comment: @jfriend00 In that case, go ahead and adjust both the question and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given this method, we don't know which syntax is the more appropriate.

Neither is appropriate as both your options employ promise anti-patterns (creating new promises when you can just work with and return the one you already have).

Assuming `req()` already returns a promise (which you imply with your use of `await`), you should just return that promise directly.  I see no reason to even use `async` or `await` here.

```
// presumably from your use of this, this is a method declaration
function finishUpgrade({id}) {
  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: this.apiUrl + `${id}/?action=proceed`,
    body: {}
    json: true
  };
  return req(options);
}

this.finishUpgrade({id: someId}).then(result => {
    // upgrade done here
}).catch(err => {
    // error here
});
```

---

When you do need to modify the return value, you just add a `.then()` handler and the modified value you return from that `.then()` handler becomes the new resolved value:

```
// presumably from your use of this, this is a method declaration
function finishUpgrade({id}) {
  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: this.apiUrl + `${id}/?action=proceed`,
    body: {}
    json: true
  };
  return req(options).then(result => {
      // change the resolved value of the promise to our data object
      let data = { someData: someValue };
      data.response = result;
      return data;
  });
}

this.finishUpgrade({id: someId}).then(result => {
    // upgrade done here
}).catch(err => {
    // error here
});
```